# If you don't take a dispensed Mega GobbleGum from the GobbleGum machine, does the game still count it as used?

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops-3

In the past, there have been times when I took a Rare GobbleGum from the machine but never used it. When I check my Rare GG after the game, I notice the Rare GG I took but never used was counted as used (say I had 5 uses of a certain Rare GG before the game, and during the game, I took said Rare GG from the machine but didn't use it at any point. After the game, said Rare GG had 4 uses left).

I played Nacht Der Toten from the Zombies Chronicles DLC recently and got a Rare GG from the GG Machine. I didn't take it, however, and after the game noticed the uses of that Rare GG had not gone down by one.

So should I be more careful when deciding whether to take a Rare GG?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how the mechanic works.  Once you **take** the gobblegum from the machine, it's deducted from your total amount of them.  Whether or not you consume it does not matter. If you leave it, it will not deduct it from your total number of them.

[This Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/CODZombies/comments/3ttxqo/if_i_let_a_mega_gobblegum_fall_back_into_the/) discusses this:

> ...if I don't pick up my mega gobblegum from the machine does does it use one up or do I keep it?
>
> it doesnt get used up. you "use up" a gobblegum when you take it